# Nested Recyclerview of Images not clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, xml-layout

[image]

As shown in image it have recyclerview of list and each recyclerviews item has again new recyclerview which contains list of images. the red area is getting captures click event but from same item nested recyclerview area/item not getting clicked.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_offer_product_item"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
                android:id="@+id/img_user"
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp" />

            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/colorNickname"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:id="@+id/lbl_nickname"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_user"
                android:text="U*36"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_nickname"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_positive_sm"
                    android:layout_width="14dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_positive"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="32"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextDefault"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_negative_sm"
                    android:layout_width="14dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_negative"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextDefault"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_product_name"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorProductName"
            android:text="Apple iPhone 6, 128GB, White "
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
                android:layout_width="14dp"
                android:layout_height="14dp" />

            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/darkerGray"
                android:id="@+id/txt_kms"
                android:text="1km"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_offer_product_images"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/colorTimeEndsIn"
                android:id="@+id/txt_endsin"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="00:30"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:background="@color/colorOfferProductPrice"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="32dp"
                android:paddingRight="32dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_currency"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:paddingRight="2dp"
                    android:text="d"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_price"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:text="24.750.000"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And for nested recyclerview following is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:clickable="false"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:id="@+id/img_offer_product"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <View
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share java code

Answer (score 0):

try to set clickable attribute true as above,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_offer_product_images"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Comment: also set clickable true in RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_offer_product"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You should make your view clickable. 
As I can see that you have clickable false for the view, so you need to change like this for your child item of child recyclerview.